# Wait for user to give calendar access in Swift/SwifUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, async-await, calendar

I'm working on an app in Swift/SwiftUI that requires calendar access and requests this access when users press a button during setup. However, when users press the button to give access, the expected alert shows but the app proceeds to the next screen in the background. The app should stay on the same screen and go to an error page if necessary.

This is what I've tried so far. Any help that you could give would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```swift
func getAccess() async {
    eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event) { granted, error in

    }
}
```

The below code is contained within the button.

```swift
Task {
  await getAccess()
  let authStatus = EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: .event)
  if authStatus != .authorized {
    withAnimation {
       step = step + 1
    }
  } else {
     withAnimation {
        step = step + 2
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to convert the access completion handler(old method) with a a “continuation” (new method) watch “Meet async await” from WWDC

Comment: That works, thanks! I found a great article on this concept here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/swift/5.5/continuations

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 16 and below you can convert the old

```
func requestAccess(to entityType: EKEntityType,
completion: @escaping EKEventStoreRequestAccessCompletionHandler)
```

Using a `CheckedContinuation<T, Error>`

```
func requestAccess(to: EKEntityType = .event) async throws -> Bool{
    return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
        eventStore.requestAccess(to: to) { granted, error in
            if let error {
                continuation.resume(throwing: error)
            } else {
                continuation.resume(returning: granted)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then you can use

```
let isAuthorized = try await requestAccess()
```

Something to note for iOS 17+

> 'requestAccess(to:completion:)' was deprecated in iOS 17.0: Use
> -requestFullAccessToEvents,
> -requestWriteOnlyAccessToEvents:, or -requestFullAccessToReminders:

Concurrency is built in to the new methods.